# Access variable in actionPerformed

Tags: java

I have a class SaveFile implementing ActionListener. The method in it takes a string argument compleName. How do I make completeName be accessable in actionPerformed method in that class.

Thanks

```
 class SaveFile implements ActionListener {
        public void uploadToDatabase(String completeName){

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            // I want to access completeName here
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use it as a variable inside your class

```
class SaveFile implements ActionListener {
        private string completeName;

        public void uploadToDatabase(String compName){
             //code...
             this.completeName = compName;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            System.out.println(completeName);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Simply ensure you store `completeName` as an instance variable.

```
class SaveFile implements ActionListener {
        private String completeName;

        public void uploadToDatabase(String completeName){
            // do other things
            this.completeName = completeName;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            // use this.completeName to get that value
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about 'this' keyword. –